# Why does Qt use qint64 for data lengths and offsets instead of quint64?

Tags: qt, types

`QIODevice` and the related classes use `qint64` for positions and sizes which is a signed datatype. Is there a need to express negative values? Because otherwise the 8 bytes of such a type could be used to express greater sizes, couldn't they?

Comment: Maybe they use negative values for special cases?

Comment: I guess they could be negative, in case of error, for example.

Comment: `seek` method needs negative offsets anyway. So they can't use the full range.

Comment: You mean 16 Exabyte as opposed to 8?

Comment: @cyco130: QIODevice::seek works only as SEEK_SET. The input is always from the beginning of the file, thus has to be positive.

Comment: @StephenChu Right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Christian Rau: I'm aware that this is not a practical issue (at least not today) but the question still stands nevertheless.

Comment: You might also ask why Qt's container classes take `int` instead of `unsigned int` in their indexing methods. It seems more of a habit of generally using `int` for all integers, instead of thinking about the actual range constraints and using the correct unsigned types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An error value of -1 is returned for several functions in `QIODevice`. Qt often uses a C style of error handing using return values to avoid the need for a compiler or platform that supports the use of C++ exceptions. It is important to check for these error codes.

From [the manual](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html):

- `QIODevice::write` and `QIODevice::writeData`

  > Returns the number of bytes that were actually written, or -1 if an error occurred.
- `QIODevice::read(char*,qint64)`

  > If an error occurs, ... this function returns -1.
- `QIODevice::readData(char*,qint64)`

  > ... and returns the number of bytes read or -1 if an error occurred.
- `QIODevice::peek(char*,qint64)`

  > If an error occurs, ... this function returns -1.

Comment: Correct, but still incompatible with anything STL, and IMHO a stupid design decision, `(size_t)(-1)` is equally useful/portable and much more compatible to Standard C++. But then again, Qt never was really "standard" (as opposed to stuff like Boost for example).

Comment: When writing a C++, I would normally recommend using either the Qt library or the C++ standard library (`std::`), not trying to mix them; though that is not always possible when using other libraries with Qt.